# Existing CakePHP projects force download of webroot/index.php source code

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm working on windows with Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.2.17. I've just done some fiddling to install mcrypt and since then when I try to access some (but not all) of my cakephp projects in my browser (chrome), the source code for webroot/index.php is downloaded to a file called download. If I unpack a fresh cakephp and access that it works fine.

I also get the same issue with Magento by the way.

Any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Does it work OK in other browsers? Or do they have the same problem?

Comment: It all seems to work fine in IE9 and FF. Is there any reason why chrome in particular is doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue, it turned out to be only a problem for google chrome. I emptied the cache and all is back to normal. Thanks to Oldskool for making me aware that it was possibly a browser specific issue.